# JQuery Mobile - When is JavaScript loaded into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a JQuery Mobile application and I seem to have several locations in the app where the JavaScript doesn't execute as expected. In short, I have a "Dashboard" page. If the user hasn't logged in, I use the "changePage" function to send them back to the Login page.

If I attempt to login directly via the Login page, everything works as expected. However, if I am redirected to the Login page from the Dashboard page, I see a JavaScript error that says: "loginButton_Click is not defined". To provide more insight, here is my code:

**Dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

    <script src="/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shared.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dashboardPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a id="logoutButton" href="#" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Logout</a>
      <h1>My App</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview"> 
        <li data-role="list-divider"><span id="greeting"></span></li>
      </ul><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Shared.js

```
$("#dashboardPage").live("pagecreate", function () {
});

$("#dashboardPage").live("pagebeforeshow", function () {
});

$("#dashboardPage").live("pageshow", function () {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (user == null) {
        $.mobile.changePage("/login.html", { transition: "slide" });
    }
});
```

**login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

    <script src="/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shared.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loginPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>App Name</h1></div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <label for="usernameTextBox">Username</label>
      <input id="usernameTextBox" type="text" /><br />

      <label for="passwordTextBox">Password</label>
      <input id="passwordTextBox" type="password" /><br />

      <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="return loginButton_Click();" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function loginButton_Click() {
      $.mobile.changePage("/dashboard.html", { transition: "slide" });
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like there is something that I don't understand regarding how JavaScript gets into the DOM. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shared.js add $(...) wrapper:

```
$(function(){ 

$("#dashboardPage").live("pagecreate", function () {
});

$("#dashboardPage").live("pagebeforeshow", function () {
});

$("#dashboardPage").live("pageshow", function () {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (user == null) {
        $.mobile.changePage("/login.html", { transition: "slide" });
    }
});

});
```